# Matplotlib does not display points specified from ginput

Tags: python, matplotlib

With the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

data = np.random.rand(4, 4)
plt.imshow(data)

points_xy = np.array(plt.ginput(3))

p = Polygon(points_xy, alpha=0.3)
plt.gca().add_artist(p)
plt.show()
```

The polygon is not displayed.  It does if I add this at the end:

```
plt.imshow(data)
```

Is this because the polygon is below the layer of data and when i call `plt.imshow(data)` again it moves the data layer below the polygon?

Hardcoding the points instead of using `plt.ginput()` also gives the correct result:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

data = np.random.rand(4, 4)
plt.imshow(data)

points_x = (0, 2, 1)
points_y = (0, 1, 3)
points_xy = np.array([points_x, points_y]).T

p = Polygon(points_xy, alpha=0.3)
plt.gca().add_artist(p)
plt.show()
```

Why is the polygon not displayed with my original code?

I am using Python 3.4 and matplotlib 1.4.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need a `plt.draw` before `plt.show`. After you add the artist to the axis, it is not drawn until another action tells `matplotlib` to redraw the axis. You can do that with `plt.draw`. The reason `plt.imshow` worked is because that automatically draws the axis

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

data = np.random.rand(4, 4)
plt.imshow(data)

points_xy = np.array(plt.ginput(3))
p = Polygon(points_xy, alpha=0.3)
plt.gca().add_artist(p)

plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

[image]